# How can I access elements of a list when looping through it?

Tags: r

I want to have loop which automatically goes through a dates list and then uses the respective element to access an URL. However my problem is that I don´t know how to tell R that dates[i] in the URL refers to the ith element of the dates list. In Stata for example I can do this by marking it as local, does something similar exist for R?

Below you see a simplified version of my code.

```
library('chron')
dates <- seq.dates("01/01/00", "12/31/01", by = "months")

for(i in dates){
url <- 'http://www.spiegel.de/nachrichtenarchiv/artikel-dates[i].html'
.... }
```

Best,
Rene

Comment: `url <- paste0("http://www.spiegel.de/nachrichtenarchiv/artikel-", dates[i], ".html")`?

Comment: That´s what i was looking for! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try with `glue`

```
res <- lapply(as.character(dates), function(i) 
         glue::glue('http://www.spiegel.de/nachrichtenarchiv/artikel-{i}.html'))
```

---

Or using `for` loop, loop over the sequence of 'dates', and `glue` (or `paste`) the elements together.

```
url <- vector('list', length(dates))
for(i in seq_along(dates)){
 url[[i]] <- glue::glue('http://www.spiegel.de/nachrichtenarchiv/artikel-{as.character(dates[i])}.html')
 }
```

NOTE:  This can be done without any loop though.  Here, we assume that is needed

```
glue::glue('http://www.spiegel.de/nachrichtenarchiv/artikel-{dates}.html')
```

Or with `sprintf` from `base R`

```
sprintf('http://www.spiegel.de/nachrichtenarchiv/artikel-%s.html', dates)
```

Comment: This works too! However due to simplicity I prefer the solution of Cath. Thank you very much for your effort!